# Upgrading ERb tags for Rails 3 upgrade. Should I: <%= end %> as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-3-upgrade

Given a block of rails 2.3.x ERb code:

```
<% form_for account, :url => { :action => :invite } do |f| %>
  # blah
<% end %>
```

using the Rails upgrade plugin, it tells me that I need to replace `<%` with `<%=` should I also do this for the `end` line? Such as:

```
<%= form_for account, :url => { :action => :invite } do |f| %>
   # blah
<%= end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you would only need <%= when you start a block.

So it would be:

```
<%= form_for account, :url => { :action => :invite } do |f| %>
   # blah
<% end %>
```

See this [rails/asciicast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/208-erb-blocks-in-rails-3) for upgrading to the new erb.