# No inline blocks in ERB helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, syntax, erb, view-helpers

I was curious: in an ERB file, when passing a block to a view helper, why does **this** work:

```
<%= div_for @thing do |x| %>
  <%= x %>
<% end %>
```

while **this doesn't**?

```
<%= div_for @thing {|x| x.to_s} %>
```

In Ruby, `do...end` is exactly the same as `{...}`, so why not in ERB? Note aside: I can use `x` on its own on the second line above because its `.to_s` method returns the field I want to render. Sorry if this has been asked before, I wasn't able to find a similar question (found a  [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5454651/1030985) though).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the second block of code is exactly the same as:

```
<%= div_for @thing do |x| %>
  <% x %>
<% end %>
```

Because the x doesn't have a "=" on it, it's not going to be output in your view.
Try :

```
<%= div_for @thing {|x| concat x.to_s} %>
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work either. The error is "`undefined method arity for nil:NilClass`" and is caused by line 101 of `ActionView::Helpers::RecordTagHelper` (see http://is.gd/nFRmQc). Somehow the `{|inline| block}` seems to return `nil` in ERB...